# Django POST fails date format validation, even with input_formats

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 1.6 with postgres.

I have read other questions on setting up DATE_INPUT_FORMATS, using input_formats and have tried several combinations but the start_date field still fails validation with:

```
[u"'09/05/2014' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]
```

I have tried changing USE_L10N to False, playing with the input_formats in the form, changing the model from DateTimeField, to DateTime, even adding the format to the widget, to no avail. Below are the current settings. I feel like this is a simple error but I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. How can I get Django to accept the input '09/05/2014'?

settings.py

```
TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%m/%d/%Y','%Y/%m/%d','%Y-%m-%d',)
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%m/%d/%Y','%Y/%m/%d','%Y-%m-%d',)
```

models.py

```
...
class RecurringTransaction(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    amount = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    interval = models.CharField(choices=INTERVAL_CHOICES, default="months", max_length=10)
    occurrences = models.IntegerField()
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    repeats = models.IntegerField(choices=REPEAT_CHOICES, default=1)
    end_type = models.IntegerField()
```

forms.py

```
class RecurringTransactionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    start_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%m/%d/%Y','%Y/%m/%d','%Y-%m-%d',])
    end_date = forms.DateField(required=False, input_formats=['%m/%d/%Y','%Y/%m/%d','%Y-%m-%d',])

    class Meta:
        model = RecurringTransaction
        fields = ('amount','category','interval','occurrences','start_date','end_date','active','repeats','end_type')
        widgets = {
            'interval': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id':'interval'}),
            'repeats': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id':'repeats'}),
            'category': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id':'category_id'}),
        }
```

views.py

```
...
def add_edit_recurrence(request, id=None):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        recurring_trx = RecurringTransaction.objects.filter(id=id).first()
        recurring_trx_form = RecurringTransactionForm(request.POST, instance=recurring_trx)
        #print recurring_trx_form.errors

        if recurring_trx_form.is_valid():
            recurring_trx_form.save()

    else:
        recurring_trx_form = RecurringTransactionForm()

return render_to_response("recurrence_new.html",{"recurring_trx_form":recurring_trx_form}, context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your form like this:

```
class RecurringTransactionForm(forms.ModelForm):

        '''
        I have added a class with each date/datetime field so that I could attach Jquery date picker to those classes.Its unnecessary if you don't need it.
        '''
        def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
            super(RecurringTransactionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['start_date'] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'date-selector'}))
            self.fields['end_date'] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'date-selector'})) 


        def clean_start_date(self):
            return datetime.datetime.strptime(self.cleaned_data['start_date'], '%m-%d-%Y')
        def clean_end_date(self):
            return datetime.datetime.strptime(self.cleaned_data['end_date'], '%m-%d-%Y')


        class Meta:
            model = RecurringTransaction
            fields=['active', 'category',... ] #ignore start_date and end_date from this list
```

Comment: I tried this but it's throwing a type error. "must be string, not datetime.date" So strptime can't parse a date, but if it's getting a date, then I'm even more confused about the first error

Comment: you have to remove start_date and end_date from Meta 's fields section. I have updated my answer

Comment: If you are getting a date, then just ignore the clean method @user2352879 :)

Comment: This is working, thanks for your help. Can you explain why it doesn't work to just use input_formats on the model form field?

Comment: I think probably because you are using datetimefield in model, and its not validating by input format.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the start_date to be a DatetimeField?...If you are going to capture the date only, try a DateField.